# disabling button on hover and click cursor not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add a common class name 'btn-common' to all buttons
then similar common class 'btn' to all buttons, set the width of each button to 100px and the height to 40px, remove the border of the button and set the border radius to 10px.

- Add a class name btn1 to the first button, set the cursor to click when the mouse passes over it in the class name
- Add a class name btn2 to the second button, this button is disabled and the cursor becomes disabled when the mouse passes over it

I have done those except the last 2 - hover and click on buttons, it's not working.

```css
.btn {
    width:100px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}


.btn1{
  cursor: pointer;
}


.btn2:disabled{
   
  cursor:disabled;
}

.btn-common {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./common.css">
    <title>Button</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root">
      <button class="btn-common btn btn1">Click me!</button>
      <button class="btn-common bnt btn2">Don't touch me!</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have an error in the class name here `<button class="btn-common bnt btn2">Don't touch me!</button>`. error is here - `bnt`

Comment: and pseudo class `:disabled` does not make the button disabled, but simply identifies it as disabled

Comment: `<button disabled  class="btn-common btn btn2">Don't touch me!</button>` you have to add ```disabled``` to apply  pseudo class `:disabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn {
    width:100px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}


.btn1{
  cursor: pointer;
}


.btn2:disabled{
   
  cursor:not-allowed;
}

.btn-common {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./common.css">
    <title>Button</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root">
      <button class="btn-common btn btn1">Click me!</button>
      <button disabled class="btn-common btn btn2">Don't touch me!</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create two new classes .pointer and  .disable and use accordingly

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        background: orange;
      }

      .btn {
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
      }

      .btn-common {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
      }

      button.pointer {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      button.disable:hover {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="root">
      <button class="btn btn-common pointer">Click me!</button>
      <button class="btn btn-common disable">Don't touch me!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cursor: disabled;` does not exist, change it to `cursor: not-allowed;`.

But you don't need to use extra classes for that. In this scenario it should be enough to do something like this:

```
.btn {
    cursor: poiner;
}
.btn[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Then you will have to just add `disabled` to the button.

```
<button class="btn-common btn" disabled>Don't touch me!</button>
```